# Show list of clients of wifi hotspot Mac OS X

Tags: macos, network, internet-sharing

I have MacBook Air and I access internet using ethernet to USB adapter. Now I'm sharing Wi-Fi to my other devices, but I want to know the information about all clients of my hotspot. Not only mac address, but names and time they're connected too. Is there a way to do that or an app?

Answer (score 7):

I get the list using `arp` command at Terminal.

first, get your WiFi sharing interface name, I get it by typing `ifconfig` on terminal.

It should be something like `bridgexxx`, for me, it's `bridge100`

Then type this on terminal:

`arp -i interfacename -a`

for me the command was like:

`arp -i bridge100 -a`

it shows the internal ip addresses and mac addresses of the devices connected.